# Custom back UIBarButton with same title as the original?

Tags: ios, button, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back

I'd like to send a confirmation UIAlertView when leaving a page via the backBarButtonItem of my current UIViewController.

To do this, I replaced the existing back button with a new UIBarButtonItem:

```
- (void) setBackButton {
NSArray * viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController * previousController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:[viewControllers count]-2];

self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:previousController.title style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
previousController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = self.backButton;
```

}

The problem is thus: I can't seem to get a callback to @selector(backButtonPressed) in my current UIViewController. When putting self.backButton in self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem it does work, but the button is a rectangle instead of an arrow.

How to get a button that looks exactly the same as the original back button that allows for a @selector(backButtonPressed) method to be called instead of just going back?

Comment: I'm not sure which way would solve the problem as i'd use the navController delegate for such purpose with `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` comparing the argument controller with the previous in the stack because you normally don't try to push the previous controller.

Comment: willShowViewController indicates that the previous UIVIewController will be shown regardless of actions taken. I'd like the user to be able to prevent this from happening after accidentally hitting the backbutton.

Answer (score 0):

For an arrow-shaped button you should initiate the UIBarButtonItem with a custom view (which has an arrow-shaped image). But it is not very common to overwrite the back buttons action in a navigation controller. Instead of that, you should present the screen modally and add bar buttons there (done, cancel). Hope this helps!